# Content of the various sets of Chabad books

Tags: torah-study, jewish-books, chabad

I was wondering about the differences between the various sets of Chabad books by the Rebbe, for example, Likkutei sichos vs sefer hasichos vs likkutei sichos parshioyos, sefer maamorim, sefer maamorim melukat, Moshiach ve Geulah.

What are the differences between all these??

Comment: https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%D7%98%D7%A9

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87838/learning-chabad-sichos

Answer (score 2):

- **Likkutei Sichos** is a collection of select essays on specific topics in Torah, written up by a committee of chassidim, based on talks by the Rebbe over the years and edited by him. They were originally printed for distribution as booklets, and over time they were compiled into 39 seforim. Each sefer (except the first four) covers one chumash, with 2-3 sichos for each parsha and special occasion. Some parts are in Yiddish and some are in Hebrew.
- **Sefer Hasichos** is a compilation of the Rebbe's talks spanning the years 5747-5752. They were printed in chronological order and were more of a direct transcript than the reworked Likkutei Sichos. Some were translated to Hebrew, and they were all edited by the Rebbe.
- **Likkutei Sichos - Parshiyos** combines and reorganizes the two sets into one sefer per parsha (or special occasion) instead of the original ordering.
- **Sichos Kodesh** is a collection of unedited talks in the original Yiddish, in chronological order.
- **Sefer Hamaamarim** is a set of maamarim said by the Rebbe over the years, mostly unedited. A maamar is an in-depth, canonical discourse on chassidus, preceded by a special niggun and delivered in a unique manner, with chassidim standing for the duration. At a farbrengen there would typically be one maamar interposed between any number of sichos. These were always written up in Hebrew.
- **Sefer Hamaamarim - Melukat** is a selection of maamarim that were edited by the Rebbe for distribution over the years, similar to Likkutei Sichos. They were originally printed in 6 volumes in order of distribution, and they were eventually reprinted as a 4-volume set organized by the months of the year.
- **Toras Menachem - Hisvaaduyos** is the most comprehensive set, compiling all the extant maamarim and sichos (translated to Hebrew) into a single chronological work. The first published volumes were from 5741-5752, and they're currently printing the rest, starting from 5710.

Comment: wait likkutei sichos is not written by the Rebbe?

Comment: They were compiled from his talks and edited by him. The Rebbe didn't really write chassidus like his predecessors. Most of what we have was given orally.